# webkit and mozilla full-screen mode

Tags: fullscreen

I know this has only just been introduced lately, so if I use it, how can I test if a browser supports it?

If  I do something like the following, I believe I am testing if the browser is in full screen mode not whether or not the browser offers the functionality?

```
function FullScreenSupported() { 
  if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
    alert("webkitIsFullScreen is supported");/ 
  } else {
    alert("webkitIsFullScreen is not supported"); 
  }
}
```

Mozilla’s introduction to full screen mode is here: [Using fullscreen mode – AutoCompatibilityTable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode#AutoCompatibilityTable)
.

Comment: I resolved this as: document.webkitIsFullScreen != null

Comment: You can answer your own questions, you know :)

Comment: But that solution only works in webkit browsers

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://gist.github.com/helgri/1336232) a function that makes use of Modernizr to do that.

I refactored the code to make it work without Modernizr too:

```
function FullScreenSupported() {
    var ancelFullScreen = 'ancelFullScreen';

    // FF9 pre-check
    if(document.mozCancelFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreenEnabled) {
        return false;
    }

    domPrefixes = [ 'moz', 'webkit' ];

    var limit = domPrefixes.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        if(document[domPrefixes[i].toLowerCase() + 'C' + ancelFullScreen])
            return true;
    }

    return !!document['c' + ancelFullScreen] || false;
};
```

I've tested it with Firefox 19, Chrome 25, Safari 5, IE8 and it seems to work :)